# ways to return an updated instance of a class python

Tags: python, class, instance, decorator

it  is my simple decorator
there is some main() with cls = CLS()

```
def main():
    ....
    cls = CLS()
    result = func1(cls, some_data)
    >>> new cls Instead of old cls

@decorator
def func1(*, **)
```

i want to replace old cls to new cls  if was exeption in decorator
i can use global variable
i can use return cls
is any more ways to replace ? with out global vars or return

```
   def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            connection = cls.connection
            data = func(*args, **kwargs)
            While True: 
                try:
                    result = connection(data)
                except:
                    cls = CLS()
                    connection = cls1.connection
            return result
      return wraper
```

Comment: Just return a tuple in `wrapper`: `return result, cls`?

Comment: I wrote above about it that I can return it but that's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CLS:
_instance = None
.....

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance
```

and

```
connection = cls._instance.connection
```

its work

Answer (score 0):

Without a return value or a global variable, your only option is to use a wrapper object so that you can change the reference in the decorator. The question is, if you really need to update the `CLS` or just the `connection`.

So you could do this instead:

```py
cls.connection = new CLS().connection
```

The idea remains the same, it just a question whether you need an additional wrapper. The `cls` in `main` will have the updated `connection`.